# SQL Server Agent Job running slowly

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I am running a simple script however table is large with several columns selected and doing

```
SELECT <columns>....
INTO <table>
FROM TABLE
```

The query execution takes ~25 seconds if I execute in SSMS while the same takes > 30 minutes if I run it within an agent job.

The SQL Agent service running under default account, and I tried to apply MADOP/NOLOCK/RECOMPILE options, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler when SQL Agent is running the job?

Comment: @devlincarnate, I did not but I checked the current running queries and there were no blockings. The wait type it was stuck at SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD.

Comment: Check and try to replicate the same SET options that you use when you run the query in SSMS. You can find out how to check with: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/

That should be the only difference between SSMS and the Agent

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan, you are right. The difference between Agent and SSMS is the SET options. In my case, it was QUOTED_IDENTIFIER needs to be ON. Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The query was running slow within an Agent job and there has to be `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` used before executing the query.
This solved my issue.